# merging a view with template view django

Tags: python, django, class, merge, function

I want that the landing page of my homepage is a form with an input and the user puts in stuff. So I followed a couple of tutorials and now I have this:

views.py:

```
def create2(request): 
  if request.method =='POST':
    form = LocationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():   
      form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('')
  else:
    form = LocationForm()

  args = {}
  args.update(csrf(request))
  args['form'] = form
  return render_to_response('location/index.html', args)
```

and in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', 'core.views.create2'),
```

which works perfectly fine, if I go to 127.0.0.1:8000 I get to index.html and when put in something in the input it gets saved in the database. However, the old part of my homepage looks like this

```
class LandingView(TemplateView):
    model = Location
    template_name="location/index.html"
    def search
    ...
```

and the urls.py: 
`url(r'^$', core.views.LandingView.as_view(), name='index')`,

which has a function `search` I So my question is, is there a way how I can merge the `def create2` into my `LandingView`. I tried several things, but I am always ending up having the index.html without the input field. I also tried

```
def create2 
...
def search
...
```

but didn't work.

Does anyone know how to merge that together?

**EDIT**
Thank you the working solution looks like this now

```
class Create(CreateView):
  model = coremodels.Location
  template_name = 'location/test.html'
  fields = ['title']
  def form_valid(self, form):
     form.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect('')

    return super(Create, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the results you are looking for, there are multiple ways to solve this:

**1. Use `CreateView` and `UpdateView`**

Django already provides some classes that render a form for your model, submit it using `POST`, and re-render the form with errors if form validation was not successful.

Check the [generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) documentation.

**2. Override `get_context_data`**

In `LandingView`, override `TemplateView`'s [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) method, so that your context includes the form you are creating in `create2`.

**3. Use `FormView`**

If you still want to use your own defined form instead of the model form that `CreateView` and `UpdateView` generate for you, you can use [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview), which is pretty much the same as `TemplateView` except it also handles your form submission/errors automatically.

---

In any case, you can keep your `search` function inside the class-based view and call it from `get_context_data` to include its results in the template's context.

Comment: if I just write the def create2 in a class, is there any way I can access it with the urls? I tried url(r'^$', 'core.views.LandingView.create2'), but didnt work

Comment: No, but you can make `create2` return `form` instead of `render_response`, and then call `context['form'] = create2(self.request)` inside `get_data_context`.

Comment: Awesome! I am using createView, thank you so much ! I updated my code

Comment: So i tried my code if an else statement and without but I couldn't see any difference. Do I need the else statement?

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked for you! :) You don't need to override `form_valid` in this case, `CreateView` automatically saves the model on submission. You should override it only if you need some extra handling, or if you were using `FormView` instead of `CreateView`. So, right now you could just remove `form_valid` completely. To redirect after form submission just use `success_url` in your view (there are some examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/)).

Comment: If I want to implement two fields from different class in the model.py can I still do that?  Is there an easy way to import them both? Let's say model = Location, Country, and then fields = ['title', 'name'] ?

Comment: Hold on, how do you mean the solution with the create2 get_context_data? Do you mean like that   
`def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(LandingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = create2(self.request)
    return context`
and the `return form` in the  `create2`